# Powershell ISE utf8 input different than Ruby's

Tags: ruby, powershell, utf-8

I have found myself forced to work with Ruby on Windows 7 (Home Premium) and I've been having lots of problems with encoding. As long as I didn't need console input, I was rather good however, but now I'm stymied.

I'm using Powershell ISE and have executed the command `chcp 65001` to make it utf-8. Still my input into ruby programs is incompatible with what's inside Ruby. I've installed Ruby with RubyInstaller 1.9.3.
Okay, what's the problem then?

I've written a short example:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
target = ARGV[0]
puts "string constant ="+ "dupą"
puts "dupą".bytes.to_a.to_s
puts "dupą".encoding
puts "target =" +target
puts target.bytes.to_a.to_s
puts target.encoding
puts target.eql? "dupą"
```

Alright, now let's run this example:

```
PS C:\Users\user\ruby\2> ruby example.rb dupą
string constant =dupą
[100, 117, 112, 196, 133]
UTF-8
target =dup�
[100, 117, 112, 185]
UTF-8
false
```

So the bytes in two identical strings are different, but still they're both recognized as UTF-8.

Obviously I'm missing something. What am I missing?

Comment: I'd be very much surprised if `chcp` worked at all in the PowerShell ISE ...

Comment: And why is that? Before using the command, it displays gibberish instead of my diacritics just like normal PowerShell. The situation described in my question is exactly the same in both PS and PS ISE. In both cases only chcp allows Ruby to return UTF-8 as `target`'s encoding. Before that, it returns CP852. The byte sequence is still `[100, 117, 112, 185]` however.

Comment: `chcp` is a command for `cmd.exe` (and, previously, `command.com`). ISE doesn't use Window's console subsystem for UI, so it will have no effect.

Comment: I'm still getting the very same behaviours in both PowerShell and Powershell ISE after using the `chcp` command, no matter what ISE does or doesn't use. In my experience it very much does have an effect. This is not the question at hand however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since i haven't your special a char on my keyboard i used some other.
You need to be sure your ruby script is saved in UTF-8 encoding itself.
Then try this, on the second line replace the cp with yours. Success !!

```
# encoding: utf-8
target = ARGV[0].dup.force_encoding('CP1252').encode('UTF-8') # => true
#target = ARGV[0] # => false
puts "string constant = déjà"
puts "déjà".bytes.to_a.to_s
puts "déjà".encoding
puts "target =" +target
puts target.bytes.to_a.to_s
puts target.encoding
puts target.eql? "déjà" # =>true
```

Comment: This does in fact work, but it doesn't exactly solve the problem. Nevertheless, I have employed this as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `$OutputEncoding` variable to `UTF8Encoding` or `UnicodeEncoding`.

From [about_Preference_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347731.aspx):

> ### $OutputEncoding
>
> ```
>    Determines the character encoding method that Windows PowerShell 
>    uses when it sends text to other applications. 
>
>    For example, if an application returns Unicode strings to Windows
>    PowerShell, you might need to change the value to UnicodeEncoding
>    to send the characters correctly.
>
>     Valid values: Objects derived from an Encoding class, such as
>                   ASCIIEncoding, SBCSCodePageEncoding, UTF7Encoding, 
>                   UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, and UnicodeEncoding.
>
>     Default: ASCIIEncoding object (System.Text.ASCIIEncoding)
> ```

Comment: Sadly, this did not change a thing. In fact, the example that your link provides does not work for me either.

Comment: I expect this is about pipeline to/from other (console) applications, not `out-host` and `write-host` which are natively integrated to the PSH host.

Comment: It seemed liked this would of been it. Ruby being the external program. Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/11/outputencoding-to-the-rescue.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you might typo?

try this on PSISE.

ruby example.rb (([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString((100, 117, 112, 196, 133))))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```